# Как продолжить выполнять в фоне запущенный пользователем в браузере скрипт, даже если пользователь ушёл с сайта?

Tags: php

Предположим, пользователь зашёл на страницу, которая что-то долго выполняет, а потом не дождался окончания выполнения и вышел. Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт продолжил выполнятся в фоне до самого конца?

Крон не предлагать.

Comment: а почему вы думаете, что php узнает об уходе пользователя и прервется?

Comment: @splash58 потому что у меня уже такое было

Comment: Он точно прервался из-за ухода пользователя, а не потому что время на выполнение кончилось?

Comment: @AndrewHobbit точно

Comment: @DeFF Как вам удалось это установить?

Comment: @Олег у меня стоит достаточное время на выполнение и всегда, если не уходить со страницы, скрипт успевал всё сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вначале скрипта выставить

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

Также скрипт может прерываться не по причине закрытия браузера, а так как имеется ограничение на время выполнения скрипта. Чтобы этого избежать, используйте функцию [**set_time_limit**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php)